# Noun for keeping one's property

Tags: word-request, nouns

I am describing a comparison between two situations:

1. A government (e.g. a communist one) that takes all the property of everyone and re-divides it.
2. A government (e.g. a welfare state) that taxes some of the property of the rich people but lets them keep most of their property.

I am looking for a general noun that describes, in the second situation, the fact that people are allowed to keep their property. It should be used in the following sentence:

> The second government satisfies the **partial ___________** principle, which means that each person is allowed to keep a part of his property.

I am looking for a word which emphasizes the fact that they "keep" and "remain" with (some of) their current property

Maybe "persistence" or "consistency"? Something similar to these?

Comment: What if we invert the expression from "partial preservation" to "limited intervention"? That is, the govt. embarks upon an inteverntion into the citizens' property affairs, but only partial.

Comment: partial appropriation?

Comment: @CopperKettle this is possible, but I prefer to speak positively..

Comment: partial redistribution  principle

Comment: I am looking for a word which emphasizes the fact that they "keep" and "remain" with (some of) their current property.

Comment: @User1 doesn't appropriation mean "to take"?

Comment: Yes, it does. So if the government appropriates only some, you keep the rest. And that is a positive thing. And I think you should add the info in [this comment](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73327/noun-for-keeping-ones-property?noredirect=1#comment140616_73327) to your question. That specifies what you are asking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The second government satisfies the partial [***retention***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/retention) principle, which means that each person is allowed to keep a part of his property.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that it might be "partial *ownership* principle"

Comment: I am looking for a word which has a meaning similar to "remain" and "keep".